# How to extend a core Product List Block model?

Tags: blocks, catalog, overrides

I want to extend pring a function into magento where I assemble some product data.

In the end I want to call a function like `$this->getAlternateTitle()` within Lists and Products.

This is what I have:
app/etc/modules/Namespace_Name.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

then I'm making the config in app/code/local/Namespace/Catalog/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
                <class>Namespace_Catalog_Block_Product_List</class>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And finally defining the function here:
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Product/List.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {
    public function makeBlue() {
     echo "Blueberrys are colorful";
    }
}
```

I am only getting back: `Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::makeBlue`

What do I do wrong here? It's my first magento-function so please be kind with me ;)

Comment: The answers below are correct. Depending on your needs, I would like to suggest the use of event observers to avoid block rewrites. It could help avoiding conflicts between modules in case several modules rewrite the same block.

Comment: I need this in many views. Is there a way to "copy" it automatically to each other block i need it in?

Comment: Is the function makeBlue the exact same function you need or is that just a sample function. Depending on the function, you may not need to do all this and just use an helper instead.

Comment: Actually I want a function available EVERYWHERE I touch a product. It is a logic, rendering some Product attributes together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***config.xml***

```
  <global>

    <blocks>

            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Namespace_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Product_List</product_list>
                <product_view>Namespace_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>

    </blocks>
  </global>
```

**Write class :**

app/code/local/Namespace/Catalog/Block/Catalog/Product/List.php

> ```
> <?php
> class Namespace_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
> {
> }
> ```

**app/code/local/Namespace/Catalog/Block/Catalog/Product/view.php**

> ```
> <?php
> class Namespace_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
> {
> }
> ```

Comment: That works! Thank you. I understood it a lot more now.

Comment: What do I have to do to have the function written in view and copied in list?

Comment: you are welcome:)

Comment: yes.. you need write on List.php & View.php

Comment: Amit, is there a way to recall it within the second class or do I have to copy it by hand?

Comment: just do copy...

Comment: Sorry if I'm late to the party but what if I want to have another block that is already rewriting this block? Like, can I use more then one extending class in list.phtml?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Magento's class rewrite system to extend the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` Block. The following code sample should give you a good start on how to do that:

In `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Name.xml`:

```
...
<Namespace_Catalog>
   ...
   <depends>
       <!-- This dependency ensures that your module is loaded after the core module that you are extending. -->
       <Mage_Catalog/>
   </depends>
</Namespace_Catalog>
...
```

In `app/code/local/Namespace/Catalog/config.xml`:

```
...
<blocks>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_list>Namespace_Catalog_Block_Product_List</product_list>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
....
```

If you need more details, this [tutorial by Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-overriding-in-magento-blocks--cms-23325) is a great resource.