# Override or rewrite blocks magento? Best practice

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, overrides, category-products

I know that **overriding** and **rewriting** is not the same thing, in some cases we should override instead of rewrite like the abstract classes for exemple, but i found several replies which propose to override a block magento like catalog block product list ! But for me it's better to rewrite them right ?

Now i would like to have a clarification about rewriting a block **catalog block product list**, i want to add some filter in collection product of `catalog/product/list.phtml` so i think that the only way is to rewrite the block who prepare this collection, someone can tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override core catalog block product list?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-to-override-core-catalog-block-product-list)

Comment: @Fabian Schmengler had replied me and i validated his answer.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> found several replies which propose to override a block magento like catalog block product list

Not everybody makes this distinction. Either they meant "rewrite" or it was questionable advice.

> Now i would like to have a clarification about rewriting a block catalog block product list, i want to add some filter in collection product of catalog/product/list.phtml so i think that the only way is to rewrite the block who prepare this collection, someone can tell me where I can find it?

The class is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`. But **you don't need to override or rewrite it at all**.

There is an event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` that is triggered immediately before the collection is loaded. Write an observer for this event and add your filters there.

See: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L159-L161

Comment: Thank you@Fabian Schmengler's for you reply, and as the question date, I found the solution, I rewrited the block and I addee my custom collection and it works

Answer (score 1):

You should be follow below links to solve your issue :

[How to override core catalog block product list?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-to-override-core-catalog-block-product-list)

[How to extend a core Product List Block model?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84474/how-to-extend-a-core-product-list-block-model)